# Canvas not capturing mouse position when hovered over an <h1> on top of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using React Three Fiber to animate a 3d model looking at the mouse. This is creating a canvas element in the background of my page. I have a few divs and h1s layered on top of it, and whenever my mouse hovers over the divs/h1s, the canvas freezes, until I mouse out of it. This results in a choppy looking animation. How do I rectify this?

This is my React Component:

```
function Model() {
  const { camera, gl, mouse, intersect, viewport } = useThree();
  const { nodes } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, '/scene.glb');
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const group = useRef();

  useFrame(({ mouse }) => {
    const x = (mouse.x * viewport.width) / 1200;
    const y = (mouse.y * viewport.height) / 2;
    group.current.rotation.y = x + 3;
  });
  return (
    <mesh
      receiveShadow
      castShadow
      ref={group}
      rotation={[1.8, 40, 0.1]}
      geometry={nodes.HEAD.geometry}
      material={nodes.HEAD.material}
      dispose={null}></mesh>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to add `pointer-events:none` to the overlapping elements so they'll stop blocking mouse events from reaching the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to assign a special CSS rule to your `<h1>` and `<div>`s so that they don't capture pointer events:

```css
h1 {pointer-events: none;}
```

This means the element is never the target of pointer events, so the `mousemove` event sort of "passes through" to the element below it. See [the MDN docs for further description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Comment: But what if the h1 contains a link, that I need to be able to accept pointer events?

Comment: Then you can add `pointer-events: auto` to the child `<a>` anchor tag.